# How to rewrite this type of urls and create an entry page?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a php script, which creates urls like this:

```
domain.com/model/sunny-leone-133.html
domain.com/model/stoya-2.html
domain.com/model/kagney-linn-karter-14.html
```

I want all of them to appear as something like this:

```
domain.com/model/sunny-leone
```

The number on the end are needed for database lookups, so I guess they would be there, but now visible to the visitors, if this can be done this way.

I would then want to crate an entry page, something like this:

```
domain.com/go
```

and this could be entered with something like this:

```
domain.com/go?m=sunny-leone
domain.com/go?m=stoya
domain.com/go?m=kagney-linn-karter
```

and this would be redirecting to the specific model pages. I can work on that part, I am just not sure how to do the first, rewriting part, and if this can work this way. All model names would be unique.

Thanks.

Comment: in order to have this `domain.com/model/sunny-leone` you have to change your DB to look up by name instead of ID if you leave off the number. There's no magical way to do that. :) Then just change your PHP to create the links in the form you want instead .html version.

Comment: Changes in the database are not possible, this is how they wrote the program. The other program by this company is like this too. I thought that it was not good right from the start, and not there is obstacles like this... Anything can be done, as far as I know, somehow, possibly...

Comment: Unless the code is obfuscated then changes are always possible. It's just the query that changes not necessarily the DB schema.

Comment: The script is 98% (or something like this) unencoded, but I dont want to be changing this. I guess I can use a url shortener for this. Not the best option, but there may be nothing better than this, it looks like...

Comment: If it's a social networking script or CMS there are tons, and most of those are 100% open source. Even paid ones. If you can't do something the way you want, try another one. I wouldn't stick with something that I wont be able to scale or be able to change 100% of the code if I want. It could be big and you need that freedom.

Comment: I can probably do something like this: a) create a list of all the model pages, something like this domain.com/models/alec-knight-101.html b) create an entry page at domain.com/in.php c) crate a url like domain.com/in?m=alec-knight d) this will go to the age verification entry page, and when people click yes, they will get redirected to /models/alec-knight-101.html, as long as I would store all these pages in some kind of data base or file.